# Automated web interface testing and locked screens

Tags: ruby, watir, rautomation

I'm using my desktop to automate getting files from a site using RAutomation and Watir.  I couldn't find anything on how RAutomation works with a locked screen if at all.  There might be better ways to do this but I'm now more interested in knowing if it's possible to automate sending keys through RAutomation still works or it doesn't just because of the locked screen.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to interact with the windows and their controls when the screen has been locked. It is a security feature of Windows.

However, you could do something through Remote Desktop. Maybe the discussion at this issue might help you:
https://github.com/jarmo/RAutomation/issues/69